# What to compile a new/custom language to?

Tags: compiler-construction, code-generation, machine-code

I wrote a little programming language (mostly for educational purposes and for fun, but also for proof of concepts and stuff).

What I made is a grammar using antlr and a compiler that validates the code.

After validation, the compiler should puke some lower level code, something like JVM Bytecode or CIL Bytecode.

However, I am wondering, what would be a good choice to go for at this point.

What I am afraid of is that my language features cannot be implemented in the bytecode variant.
For example JVM Bytecode does not have unsigned numeric primitive types, and doesn't have a definition of generic types.
CIL Bytecode on the other hand uses a different way of generics than I want to implement, so I cannot use that either.

I heard that machine code works directly on the processor, and that different versions of the processors require different bytecode.
What I am looking for is some bytecode language that can run independent from the processors (I dont care if I have to make separate builds for Windows, Linux or Mac for example, as long as all Windows machines work with the same bytecode, all Linux machines work with the same bytecode and all Mac machines work with the same bytecode).

I also want to be able to write the structure of classes (including the instance headers and such).

Basically, I want to have a low level machine language to compile my language to.
And ofcourse, it must be executable in some way.

Comment: Check out LLVM http:\\llvm.org which can emit a healthy number of processor machine code targets.

Comment: You can implement most unsigned operations in terms of JVM instructions easily, there is some trouble with division and remainder

Comment: @FrankC. I will try out LLVM then. @ harold With the JVM comes the same fear as for CIL, object structures and stuff like generics